# Firestore Document Order | - Causing item sequence issue in RecyclerView |

Tags: firebase, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on a ChatApp. I am storing messages in firestore. What ends up happening is firestore is saving those messages (as documents) and adding those documents in a random order.

I have seen questions regarding why recyclerview items are not being displayed in order. And the problem is not with the recyclerview. The problem is whatever the order of document is in firestore - recyclerview will display the items in that order.

In Firestore documents are added randomly let say I sent a message A first and then B and C, firetore is adding these documents not one after the other but randomly, sometime in middle, sometime on top, sometime on bottom.

This problem is causing my recyclerview displaying items in a random order. The reason I can say this with certainty that problem must be in firestore document order is because I logged and saw the list - it was displaying data inside it in the same order as firestore documents.

I want the recyclerview to display latest item (latest message and it should not just disappear anywhere above, between of the messages).

In first image I have sent a message "3" and the next message I sent was "4"

[image]

But it adds the next message not under the previous one but randomly at any position

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When adding a document, its automatically sort by the default order based on the **first character of the document ID** from **special char([limited](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#collections_documents_and_fields))**, **number**, next **Capital letters** then **Small letters** and **NOT** from  its **field** .

You can still sort it by the field using the filter in console or adding this query:

```
.collection("text").orderBy("message", "asc")`
```

[image]